# Convert varchar "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" to datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime2

I have a column of dates in varchar(50) format written as "dd/mm/yyyy"
I need to convert it to datetime2 format however when it runs it assumes that the format is "mm/dd/yyyy" and converts accordingly, throwing an error when the day field exceeds 12. How do I make it pull the data in the correct way?

e.g.

```
03/04/2017 00:00:00
03/04/2017 00:00:00
15/06/2017 00:00:00
15/06/2017 00:00:00
17/05/2017 00:00:00
```

with the last 3 throwing errors.

Current command:

```
select case when try_convert(datetime2,[Date]) is not null
    then cast([Date]as datetime2)
    else null
    end, [Date]
from [Source1]
```

Results:

```
2017-03-04 00:00:00.0000000  03/04/2017 00:00:00
2017-03-04 00:00:00.0000000  03/04/2017 00:00:00
NULL                         15/06/2017 00:00:00
NULL                         15/06/2017 00:00:00
NULL                         17/05/2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: The source of your problems: "I have a column of dates in varchar(50) ".

Comment: Are you sure it's `dd/mm` and not `mm/dd`? What about `04/07` ? The only solution is to *replace* that column with a proper date type. Otherwise you'll always have to deal with conversion errors or worse, wrong dates

Comment: The only thing worse than an error on production is wrong data on production...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  (VALUES ('03/04/2017 00:00:00'),
                  ('03/04/2017 00:00:00'),
                  ('15/06/2017 00:00:00'),
                  ('15/06/2017 00:00:00'),
                  ('17/05/2017 00:00:00')) V(StringDatetime))
SELECT *,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), VTE.StringDatetime, 103) AS NonStringDatetime2
FROM VTE;
```

You can find a list of style codes in the documentation: [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)

Answer (score 1):

```
convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
```

Check the results for all your provided values.

```
declare @dt varchar(50)='15/06/2017 00:00:00'
set @dt='03/04/2017 00:00:00'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
set @dt='03/04/2017 00:00:00'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
set @dt='15/06/2017 00:00:00'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
set @dt='15/06/2017 00:00:00'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
set @dt='17/05/2017 00:00:00'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is issue of DateFormat. You can easily judge that when Month is 15 it is giving error.

```
declare @st as varchar(50)='15/06/2017 00:00:00'
select Convert(DateTime2,@ST,103)
```

you can use the above code